# Storing data and not outputting with Intended Format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm storing some data from a spreadsheet which works properly after a `Debug.Print`

The data being stored is a long number starting with a single or more `0`.

I've tried using the below few different code segments and none of them are outputting what I want...

`.Cells(LR + 1, index).value = "00049875142"`

**OUTPUT:** *49875142*

`.Cells(LR + 1, index).value2 = "0008789875949898451142"`

**OUTPUT:** *8.78988E+18*

**QUESTION:** How can i get the output to add the leading `0` in the string when unloading my data back into the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the cell is formatted as text before storing value to it.

```
.Cells(LR + 1, index).NumberFormat = "@"
.Cells(LR + 1, index).value = "00049875142"
```

It will be more efficient though to not set format for each cell at a time, but do for the range before looping through and setting the values.

Comment: Great this works! I knew this too, just completely forgot about it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can either add leading zeroes with a custom number format (which doesn't seem to be standard across multiple cells) or input the data as text.

```
.Cells(LR + 1, index).value = "'00049875142"
 'more loops
.Cells(LR + 1, index).value2 = "'0008789875949898451142"
```

The second needs to be input as text in any event since it is larger than 15 digits and the 15 digit precision rule will truncate off important data.

```
.Cells(LR + 1, index).numberformat  ="00000000000"
.Cells(LR + 1, index).value = 49875142
 'more loops
.Cells(LR + 1, index).numberformat  ="@"
.Cells(LR + 1, index).value2 = "0008789875949898451142"
```